# How can save in the same table a nested object using NPoco?

Tags: c#, npoco

I have a class like this:

```
public class AuthEntity 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public AuthResource Resource { get; set; }

  public int ActionId { get; set; }
}
```

where AuthResource is:

```
public class AuthResource 
{
  public long ResourceId { get; private set; }

  public int ResourceType { get; private set; }
}
```

The table where the data is stored has the following fields:

- Id
- ResourceId
- ResourceType
- ActionId

I can read the AuthEntity well (including Resource property) but I don't know how do I  insert AuthEntity records. NPoco says that there is no Resource field. How can I map the nested object fields to the table fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The NPoco documentation says you can do this with **Mapping To Nested Objects** .

```
db.Fetch<AuthEntity, AuthResource>("select query to db")
```

Also you have to change your AuthResource to

```
public class AuthResource
{
     public long ResourceId { get; set; }
     public int ResourceType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The read operation isn't the problem, it works well. What I want to do is insert the AuthEntity object in the database and automatically map AuthResource properties to the ones in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure indicates that ResourceId and ResourceType are members of AuthEntity, and are not a separate class. If you wanted to have AuthResource as a separate class you could make AuthEntity inherit from AuthResource e.g.

```
public class AuthResource
{
     public long ResourceId { get; private set; }
     public int ResourceType { get; private set; }
}

public class AuthEntity : AuthResource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public int ActionId { get; set; }
}
```

in this way AuthEntity would contain the ResourceId and ResourceType values that you want it to have and AuthResource can be re-used for other classes that implement the same structure, which, it seems to me, is what you’re looking for.

Comment: Well, I could do that, but AuthResource must be aggregated to AuthEntity not it's parent.